# R Shiny sliderInput button ---> animate when page opens

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

Hello below is my code for the beginning of the UI section in my Shiny app:

```
shinyUI(navbarPage("Boston Food Inspections", id="nav",
  tabPanel("Interactive map",
           div(class="outer",

               tags$head(
               includeCSS("styles.css")
               ),
           leafletOutput("map", width="100%", height = "100%"),

           absolutePanel(id ="controls", class ="panel panel-default", fixed=TRUE,
                         draggable=TRUE, top=60, left='auto', right=20, bottom='auto',
                         width=300, height='auto',
                         checkboxGroupInput("status", h4("Business License Status"), bstatus,
                                            selected = "Active"),
                         checkboxGroupInput("violations", h4("Violation"), violationType, 
                                            selected="Rodents"),
                         sliderInput('period', h4("Select Time Period"),
                                     min = 2008,
                                     max = 2015,
                                     value = c(2008,2008),
                                     sep="", step=1, ticks=FALSE,animate=animationOptions(loop=T)), round=TRUE
                        )
           )
  ),
```

Right now my animation options specify that the slider will have a play/pause button. However, the sliderInput only begins playing when the user opens the app. I was wondering if anyone knew a simple way to alter the javascript so that the sliderInput begins playing as soon as the page loads?

Thank.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could click on the button once the page is loaded using `jQuery`. Here's an example:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
}

ui <- fluidPage(
        sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:",
                    min = 10, max = 500, value = 100,
                    animate=T),
        tags$script("$(document).ready(function(){
                        setTimeout(function() {$('.slider-animate-button').click()},10);
                    });")
                )

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The `tags$script` part clicks on the button. I added a `setTimeout` to delay the click by 10ms to wait for the click handler to be attached.